# how to run a service a non-root user completely?

Tags: 18.04, services, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run an application ([code-server](https://coder.com)) as a `sudo` user. This application is basically allowing me to run Visual Studio Code online. I created the service file as below: (`vsc.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Running Visual Studio Code Online

[Service]
User=dev001
Group=dev001
WorkingDirectory=/home/dev001/projects
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vsc.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see that the service file has the user and group information.

Here is the script I want to run as a service (`/usr/bin/vsc.sh`)

```
cd /home/dev001/projects
code-server -p 80 --allow-http --password somepassword
```

It runs fine but the problem is that the user who is running the process is still kept as root, but working as dev001. here is the screenshot of the terminal access via the running service:

[image: vscode terminal window screenshot]

Please help me if you have any solution to the problem.

**Edit 01:**

I have taken the nginx help to do a port forward (reverse proxy) to resolve the issue, until code-server gets matured and has the daemonised support for running directly on port 80 or 443. The one benefit I got with this approach is that I am able to install the letsencrypt ssl. so no my environment is all running as I needed to be. There are other issues thought, but they are not related to this thread.

Comment: Could it be the `ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vsc.sh` line? Does it run without /usr/bin/sudo? It sorta looks like it's dropping permissions only to elevate privileges again.

Comment: The process has to be executed as user (`dev001`) but with sudo so that it can open `port 80`. Without `sudo` a user can't open the `port 80` on the system (at least thats what I understand, I don't know how apache or tomcat or ngnix does that :) ).

Comment: I see your problem. Either you need to change the port, or you'll have to do a more complicated workaround (for example: https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/howto-run-programs-as-non-root-user-on-privileged-ports-via-systemd/). SOME services have a configuration to drop privileges after opening the privileged port; I'm assuming `code-server` has not such option.

Comment: You can run your process on a different port, that can be opened by a non-root user, and start a port forwarder service (like ```tcppm```: https://3proxy.ru/doc/man8/tcppm.8.html ) as root, which will bin to port 80 and forward this port to whatever port your service is running on

Answer (score 0):

How is your screen shot relevant?  You're showing the user and directory of your shell.  I could misunderstand, but I think some confusion lies here.

The SystemD service you have should start when you boot the machine, as the `dev001` user.  You can find this using `systemctl` or `ps aux | grep vsc.sh` or similar.  The key here is not to look at your shell, but the owner of the actual process.

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable vsc.service
sudo systemctl start vsc.service
sudo ps aux | grep vsc
```

You should see that your service is being run by the user set in your `vsc.service` file.

Comment: I believe the shell part of the the vscode UI. And if the service was running as the user, how could it open a shell as root?

Comment: Why do you want to open a shell as root?  I thought you wanted a process to run, as `dev001`, and controlled via `systemctl`.

Comment: @RyanJ.Yoder yes the shell is part of the vscode and it clearly shows that `whomi` is `root` but the pwd for the `~/project` folder belongs to `dev001`

and @earthmeLon here is the  response from ps aux
```
root@PGDevEnv001:~/projects# sudo ps aux | grep vsc
root      2221  0.0  0.0  67984  4164 ?        Ss   May03   0:00 /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vsc.sh
root      2222  0.0  0.0   4628   772 ?        S    May03   0:00 sh /usr/bin/vsc.sh
root      8072  0.0  0.0  14728  1004 pts/0    S+   00:07   0:00 grep --color=auto vsc
root@PGDevEnv001:~/projects# 
```
showing process running as root

Comment: also one more thing to point out there that the prompt is showing `#` in place of `$` so it is currently running in system administrator mode not in normal user mode.